I cant mount my NTFS SSD and none of the tutorals helped
So im trying to setup a dual boot with windows and ubuntuu with 2 drives. The first Is a NVME drive and contains 2 partitions one for each OS. The 2nd is a SATA SSD and is for bulk storage. But I cant mount either of them. all I get is this:
I also locked up a lot on Goggle and None of the tutorials seem to work. Does anybody know. Ive been at this for days now...

The version is 22.04 the version is windows 11 home, And bitlocker is disabled.

Edit your question.

Is this a legacy or UEFI install (they have different partitioning requiremets)? If you don't know, clues to help us decide are: 1) How old is the machine (2012+ will be UEFI from big manfacturers, but small shops could do the Windows install either way) 2)Was this Windows install ever running? (a running Windows legacy takes an msdos partition table, Win in UEFI mode takes a gpt partition table). 3)The pic shows a third partition, about EFI partition size, but with a UUID that's not for a FAT filesystem (FAT is required for the EFI partition). Add info to original posting.

Note that Windows updates may turn fast startup back on, setting hibernation flag which prevents the Linux NTFS driver from mounting a hibernated file system. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

This question is similar to: Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
